# Why is my Docker volume only sharing the docker-compose file?

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to containerize a Laravel application using Docker Compose, but I am failing to use a shared volume to bring in my actual project app files. My docker-compose file looks like this:

```
    version: "3.7"
services:
  app:
    build:
      args:
        user: sam
        uid: 1000
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: converter
    container_name: converter-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /var/www/
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    networks:
      - converter

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: converter-db
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./docker-compose/mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - converter

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: converter-nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker-compose/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - converter

networks:
  converter:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  app-volume:
```

and the Dockerfile for the app service:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

# Arguments defined in docker-compose.yml
ARG user
ARG uid

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd

# Get latest Composer
#RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Create system user to run Composer and Artisan Commands
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/$user $user
RUN mkdir -p /home/$user/.composer && \
    chown -R $user:$user /home/$user

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

USER $user
```

I then run `docker-compose build app` and `docker-compose up -d` to create the containers, which brings them up. When I go to check the /var/www folder of the app container using `docker-compose exec app ls -l`, the only file that shows is the docker-compose file:

[image]

Shouldn't the shared volume specified for the app service share my working directory in the app /var/www folder?

[image]

Comment: I seems `volumes:
  app-volume:` is unneccessary in your docker-compose.yml, because not used it

Comment: I accidentally left  that in when trying a different way - I've removed it now, thanks

Answer (score -1):

You need to add these config options to the **app** service in compose file:

```
links:
  - nginx
depends_on:
  - nginx
```

These options forces docker-compose to **create 1st the nginx** service, and after the **app**, this is neccessary becuse currently **nginx** is created after **app**, and nging overwrite the **/var/www** directory

Comment: I've added them, but it is still only showing some of the files, and even a project folder that isn't in the directory any more?

https://imgur.com/a/cF8fwzD

Comment: Please try to reinstall docker and docker-compose, because now I build environment with your docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile and working correctly: https://imgur.com/a/ZU7dnAj

Comment: `links:` do almost nothing in modern Docker, and `depends_on:` won't help the volume-mounting problem described in the question.

Comment: I've uninstalled and reinstalled Docker, which has got it to work - unfortunately I'm not sure why. Thank you for the help.